# How to automate installation of Windows installer on Appveyor CI?

Tags: automation, appveyor, installation

I've the installer in EXE format ([`mt5setup.exe`](https://www.metatrader5.com/en/download)) and I'd like to download it and automate the installation process on Appveyor CI. On Linux I would normally use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

Since this installer doesn't have any silent flags to use, how can I automate the installation process headlessly?

Comment: Best idea coming to my mind: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ (but out of this, writing this as an answer would be too long or link only)

Comment: Brief answer how to use it would be fine.

Comment: There's no brief answer, this mean watching the install and writing the script, the tool examples are good I think and just quoting the doc doesn't sound an answer to me :/.

Comment: And another option could be https://chocolatey.org/ (again, answering mean installing your linked software or quoting the doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation of Windows application can be automated using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) (AHK), similar as [Winetricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/blob/master/src/winetricks) does this for all common apps which support.

Here is example of AHK script which aims to install mentioned application:

```
Run, mt5setup.exe
WinWait, MetaTrader 5 Setup
ControlClick, Button1
Sleep 100
ControlClick, Button3
WinWait, MetaTrader 5 Setup, Installation successfully completed
ControlClick, Button4
Process, Wait, terminal.exe
Process, Close, terminal.exe
```

To integrate it with CI, AHK needs to be installed by downloading ZIP file, uncompressing it and passing the above AHK script. Suggested `appveyor.yml` file:

```
install:
- curl -sLo https://www.metatrader5.com/en/download
- curl -sLo http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey104805.zip
- unzip *.zip
before_test:
- dir
test_script:
- AutoHotkey.exe install.ahk
build: off
platform: x86
```

where `install.ahk` is the file to contain above AHK script which can be dynamically generated or downloaded from some repository.